# Buttons for opening a new activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

So, I have three activities/screens. On the first screen, there's a button, that when pressed, opens the second screen. On the second screen, there's a button to open screen 3, but also another button to go back to screen 1. I can't get both buttons on screen 2 to work. (Either one works and the other doesn't and vice versa).

Screen 1 Java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.part1to2);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });
   }
  }
```

Screen 2.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Screen2 extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);


    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto3);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen3.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

      });
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Screen 3.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Screen3 extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);

        }

}
```

And my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.gamer.network2"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".Screen2"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Screen3"></activity>
 </application>
 </manifest>
```

So, how do I get both buttons on Screen 2 to work at the same time?

Comment: How come you have two buttons with the same name? Is this a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Well I guess I figured I could just take the code from the button that worked, and copy it so another button would work, but I guess I forgot to change that. So I changed it now, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both buttons are the same name and are declared wrongly.

```
  Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);


    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto3);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Screen3.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

      });
    }
  });
```

Try instead:

```
    Button goto3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto3);
    goto3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           // Code here 
       }    
      });

    Button goto1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goto1);
    goto1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
            // Code here
        }    
      });
```

Edit: Cole, see below, this is code working from an app of mine, with two different buttons pointing to two different activities. I have also included the code from the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    mBtnPlayCourse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_screenstart_playcourse);
    mBtnNewCourse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_screenstart_newcourse);

    mBtnPlayCourse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent i = new Intent(Screen_Start.this, Screen_Players.class);               
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    mBtnNewCourse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent i = new Intent(Screen_Start.this, Screen_CreateCourse.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity android:name=".Screen_CreateCourse" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Screen_Players" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Comment: When you say // Code here, should I have the same code for both? I have:      Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FirstActivity.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);               for the first button, but when I have that on the second button as well, it doesn't work, but the first button does.

Comment: If you want to load different intents, then you want different code. From the code I gave you above and going by what you called your activities, you'd want this for **goto1**: `Intent myIntent = new Intent(Screen2.this, FirstActivity.class); startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);` and this for **goto3**: `Intent myIntent = new Intent(Screen2.this, Screen3.class); startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);`. Also, if this doesn't work, please explain if any errors show, what it's doing, what it's not etc.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the Logcat. When I click goto1, the Logcat says it's displayed activity Screen1 (which is right) but the goto3 button doesn't do anything at all. Nothing in the Logcat and no action in the Emulator.

Comment: Well the code is identical, you just pass different class names, so either goto3 is null or perhaps `Screen3` hasn't been declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`? Add a `Toast` message on goto3: `Toast.makeText(Screen2.this, "goto3 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` - do you get 'goto3 clicked'? If not, your button is null so you need to look at your `findViewById` code for this button. If it's not null, and a Toast displays, check your activity exists (I'd have thought you'd get an error if not though). Also try change your intent variables to unique names, e.g `myIntent1` and `myIntent2`.

Comment: Cole, I've updated my answer to provide you with a solution in code. This is how one of my apps do it, and it works fine.